# Link entire folder

Tags: c++, cmake

How can i link an entire folder into a library ?

i have to following structure

```
src/main.cpp
src/alg/alg1.cpp
src/alg/alg1.hpp
src/alg/alg2.cpp
src/alg/ ...
src/utils/something.cpp
src/utils/...
```

i could just use

```
add_library(ALG1 alg/alg1.cpp)
add_library(ALG2 .... )
......
add_library(UTIL1 utils/something.cpp)

add_executable(PROG main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(PROG ALG1 ALG2 ... UTIL1 UTIL2 ...)
```

anyway to tell it to pack the entire folder and link it ?
also some migth have deps between them

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would the following suit your needs?

```
add_library(ALG alg/alg1.cpp alg/alg1.hpp alg/alg2.cpp #... list all files)

add_library(UTIL utils/something.cpp #... list all files)

add_executable(PROG main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(PROG ALG UTIL)
```

Note that it's not recommended to use commands like `file(GLOB ...)` to collect source files, because then the build system will not regenerate if you add a file to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
file(GLOB UTIL_SOURCES utils/*.cpp)
```

To get all the source files in a directory, then just do

```
add_library(UTIL, ${UTIL_SOURCES})
```